# Apache SSI virtual include at wrong position

Tags: php, apache, ssi

Ok here is what I have:

Plain .html file in Apache with

```
<html>
<...>
 <!--#include virtual="/SSI/ssi_portlet.php" -->
<...>
</html>
```

But the result is:

```
<html>
<...>
</html>
Content of SSI PHP Script Result
```

instead of:

```
<html>
<...>
Content of SSI PHP Script Result
<...>
</html>
```

So why is the apache adding the script result at the bottom of the page instead at the place where the include tag is called?

The Apache is an Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) with PHP Version 5.4.4-14+deb7u12

Comment: Why are you using SSI for this in the first place, if your server seems to support PHP? Mixing those two often leads to complications. I’d recommend using PHP to include the file.

Comment: I could explain in detail, but sadly it would not help to resolve the issue. The customer wants to have this, and it's working on my development environment, but the production server seems like configured differently.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this issue when including a PHP file in my output HTML, which is generated by PHP. When reproducing your example, using a plain HTML file, I don't have any problems. Could I'd be that your HTML files are processed by a PHP handler?

I don't know if your still looking for a solution as the question is an old one but you or anyone else could try a possible solution I've found.

**Solution:**

Add these PHP functions to your "ssi_portlet.php" file:
`ob_flush();` and `ob_end_clean();` to the beginning and `ob_start();` to the end.

I've tested many other combinations using PHP's output control functions, [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), this it the only one that worked consistently with various scenario's.

In your example "SSI/ssi_portlet.php" could look like this:

```
<?php
ob_flush(); ob_end_clean();
echo "Content of SSI PHP Script Result";
ob_start();
```

I've tested this solution on Windows using XAMPP running Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) PHP/5.6.8.

**Reason:**

My idea why this problem occurs is still a little vague, so feel free to help.

The output that PHP generates in the include file seems to interfere with the existing output. Because they both use a buffer to output data. (more info about PHP output buffering at the end of this post)

`ob_flush();` will flush any existing output and `ob_end_clean();` will clean the buffer and turn if off. This will make sure it doesn't interfere with any existing output/buffers.

`ob_start();` is to make sure any other SSI included PHP files will work properly, but they should also contain the same solution as above.

That being said, SSI includes shouldn't be used for including large amounts of data or making a dynamic page. As output buffering is a mechanism to increase performance turning off output buffering is not the best solution. Certainly not when handling a lot of output.
It'd better to use PHP `include()` for those purposes.

**PHP output_buffering:**

PHP can use a mechanism called output buffering and it has a setting called "output_buffering", which can have 3 possible values. 
Quote from my php.ini file:

```
; Output buffering is a mechanism for controlling how much output data  
; (excluding headers and cookies) PHP should keep internally before pushing that  
; data to the client. If your application's output exceeds this setting, PHP  
; will send that data in chunks of roughly the size you specify.  
; On = Enabled and buffer is unlimited. (Use with caution)  
; Off = Disabled  
; Integer = Enables the buffer and sets its maximum size in bytes.   
output_buffering=4096
```